# Show bijectivity of $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac{x}{1-|x|}$

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

Show bijectivity of $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac{x}{1-|x|}$

So in order to show injectivity $f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$

so $\frac{a}{1-|a|}=\frac{b}{1-|b|}$. But how do I prove that?

For the surjectivity I have to show that $f(X)=Y$ when $X$ is the domain and  $Y$ the Image.

so I have to prove that $f$ image is $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}$. But how do I do that...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prove that $f$ is strictly increasing. Then, $x<y\implies f(x)<f(y)$. And it is surjective bby the intermediate value theorem and because $\lim_{x\to\pm1}f(x)=\pm\infty$.

If you want to avoid limits, you can solve the equation $f(x)=y$. Suppose that $y\geqslant0$. Then $x$ will have to be non-negative. So$$f(x)=y\iff\frac x{1-x}=y\iff-1+\frac1{1-x}=y\iff x=\frac y{1+y}.$$And, if $y\leqslant 0$, a similar argument shows that can simply take $x=\frac y{1-y}$.

Comment: Is the other way impossible or just really hard?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you find hard the idea of proving that $f$ is strictly increasing and deducing from that that it is injective? Anyway, yes, it is possible to prove it directly.

Comment: For $x\in[0,1)$: $\frac{a}{1-a}=\frac{b}{1-b}  \Leftrightarrow a(1-b)=b(1-a)   \Leftrightarrow a-b=b-a   \Leftrightarrow  2a=2b   \Leftrightarrow  a=b$. And now the same for $x\in[-1,0)$. Right?

Comment: It is for $x\in[0,1)$; it's for $a,b\in[0,1)$. And it's not $[-1,0)$; it's $(-1,0]$. FInally, you should add to that that if $a$ is negative and $b$ is positive (or the other way around), then you cannot possibly have $\frac a{1-\lvert a\rvert}=\frac b{1-\lvert b\rvert}$, because they don't have the same sign.

Comment: Is there another way to prove surjectivity. Limits haven't been taught yet.

Comment: Sure: if $y\geqslant0$, then $f\left(\frac y{1+y}\right)=y$ and if $y\leqslant0$, then $f\left(\frac y{1-y}\right)=y$. Do you want me to add this to my answer?

Comment: Yes, please. But how do I know that these statements are true?

Comment: Simply compute $f\left(\frac y{1+y}\right)$ and $f\left(\frac y{1-y}\right)$.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Why is $\frac{x}{1-x}=y\iff-1+\frac1{1-x}=y$?

Comment: Because$$-1+\frac1{1-x}=\frac{x-1}{1-x}+\frac1{1-x}=\frac x{1-x}.$$

Comment: Ok, I understand. But how does that prove $f(x)=y$ if you just solved it for $x$?

Comment: I proved that, for each $y\in\mathbb R$, there is a $x\in(-1,1)$ such that $f(x)=y$. Isn't that what surjectivity *means*?

Comment: So the last thing I have to show is that $f\left(\frac y{1+y}\right)=y$ and $f\left(\frac y{1-y}\right)=y$?

Comment: I have already shown in my answer that $f\left(\frac y{1+y}\right)=y$ when $y\geqslant0$ and the other case is similar.

Comment: So for $y\geq 0$, we have $\frac{x}{1-x}=-y$. Solved for $x=\frac y{y-1}$

Comment: No. For $y\geqslant 0$ we have $f\left(\frac y{1+y}\right)=y$ and for $y\leqslant 0$ we have $f\left(\frac y{1-y}\right)=y$.

Comment: Im referring to "And, if y⩽0, a similar argument shows that can simply take x=y/(1-y)"

Comment: That's for $y\leqslant0$. What you wrote was $y\geqslant0$.

Comment: Ah, sorry. So for $y\leqslant0$ it is correct?

Comment: No. It's $x=\frac y{1-y}$.

Comment: For $y\leqslant0$ it should be $f(x)=y\iff\frac x{1-x}=-y\iff-1+\frac1{1-x}=-y\iff x=\frac y{1-y}$

Comment: I am referring to "And, if y⩽0, a similar argument shows that can simply take x=y/(1-y)." How!?!?!?!

Comment: You forgot tht $x\leqslant0\implies f(x)=\frac x{1+x}$.

Answer (score 0):

For injectivity  note that for $a\in (-1,1)$ and $b\in (-1,1)$ we have $1-|a|>0$ and $1-|b|>0$, so $a$ and $b$ have the same sign.

Thus  $$\frac{a}{1-|a|}=\frac{b}{1-|b|}\implies a=b$$

For surjectivity let $$x=\frac{y}{1+|y|}$$ then you have $f(x)=y$

The trick with the absolute value is that $x$ and $f(x)$ always have the same sign.

Comment: Wow, beauty in simplicity. I really like the proof for surjectivity.

Comment: But how do you know if $1-|a|>0$ and $1-|b|>0$ that the signs are the same?

Comment: Thanks for your attention to the beauty of simplicity.

Comment: The fractions are equal and the denominators are positive so the numerators have the same sign.

Comment: Right, otherwise it wouldn't be equal.

Comment: I add a comment for solution of this equation: $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, so by rewriting that equation we reach to : $$ a-a|b|=b-b|a| $$, $$ a-b=a|b|-b|a| $$ , if $a,b>0$ we have: $a-b=ab-ba=0$ and if $a,b<0$ we have: $a-b=-ab+ba=0$ and we reach to $$a=b$$

Comment: and what if $a,b=0$? Is it that obvious you left it? :-)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand the "proof" for surjectivity.... :(

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your function for determined domain bellow:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{x}{1-x}, & \mbox{if }  0\le x <1 \\ \frac{x}{1+x}, & \mbox{if }   -1< x <0 \end{cases}$$

by taking first derivative of this function we reach to this:

$$f^{'}(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}, & \mbox{if }  0< x <1 \\ 0, & \mbox{if }  x=0 \\ \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}, & \mbox{if }   -1< x <0 \end{cases}$$

so for all time we have $f^{'}(x)\ge0$ so for defined domain this function is bijective.